# Laravel Blade how to use if statement for null or empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In the Blade templating engine, how to use "if" to determine null or empty?

`{{{ Auth::user()->age }}}`

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures

Comment: no this is for $foo and my problem for Auth::user()->***

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do it as bellow

```
    @if (empty(Auth::user()->age))
      // your if code
    @else
     //  your else code
    @endif
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use:

```
{{ Auth::user()->age or 'Age not provided' }}
```

so you will have more clean blade template

Comment: I don't no why It's not working for me, it always returns '1' as result, just like the result of a boolean expression.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

`{ Auth::user()->age ?: 'Age not provided' }}`

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing Jorge and Razi's answers, cleanest way to do it is this:

`{{ Auth::user()->age ?? 'Age not provided' }}`

also this:

`{{ Auth::user()->age ?: 'Age not provided' }}`

but this one **doesn't** work (I'm on Laravel 8, this only works with lower Laravel versions):

`{{ Auth::user()->age or 'Age not provided' }}`

If you try this last method, it returns 1 instead of what you want.

Also check this question: [Check if variable exist in laravel's blade directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425978/check-if-variable-exist-in-laravels-blade-directive)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, as I was using HeidiSQL as a DB Manager, I had to guarantee that the column field was really NULL. To do that, I clicked on the field with the right mouse button, clicked on "Insert value", then on "NULL". (It's the same as Shift+Ctrl+N). In the beginning, I was just entering NULL on the field, which is a String I guess, so it was always "truthy", not NULL. Doing that solved the problem for me, even writing `{{ Auth::user()->age }}`.