# Check if variable exist in laravel's blade directive

Tags: php, laravel, undefined, laravel-5, directive

I'm trying to create blade directive which echo variable (if variable defined) or echo "no data" if variable undefined.

This is my code in `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('p', function($ex) {
            error_log(print_r($ex,true));
            return '<?php $defined_vars = get_defined_vars(); if(array_key_exists(\''. $ex .'\', $defined_vars) ): echo ' . $ex . ' ; else: echo \'no data\'; endif;?>';
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Here is my index.blade.php:

```
<p class="lead">@p($myvar)</p>
```

But my directive "p" gives "no data" if variable defined.
If I use isset error occurres: `Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`

How could I check inside directives if variable defined?

Comment: So you're saying if(isset($myvar)) doesn't work?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Blade has a directive to check if a variable is set:

```
@isset($var)

@endisset
```

Comment: how do you handle else?

Comment: Like normal with an `@else`

Answer (score 33):

Try checking if the variable is empty:

```
@if(empty($myvar))
    <p>Data does not exist</p>
@else
    <p>Your data is here!</p>
@endif
```

Can also check [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/blade-check-if-variable-is-being-passed-from-controller)

Answer (score 28):

For Laravel 5.7 onwards use.

`{{ $checkvariable ?? 'not-exist' }}`

Comment: Not true, I'm getting Undefined Variable with this code, using Laravel v7

Answer (score 23):

For Laravel  version >=5.7

```
{{ $value ?? '' }}
```

For Laravel  version <5.7

```
{{ $value or '' }}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use in Blade functionality for checking isset i.e

```
{{ $checkvariable or 'not-exist' }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data

Comment: In future I want to add more complex logics to my directive. For example different style for auth user. So I want just type `p($foo)` in view instead of repeating `{{ $checkvariable or 'not-exist' }}` and  logics for auth check.

Answer (score 16):

The best and cleanest way check if a variable exists in blade:

```
 {!! !empty($myvariable) ? $myvariable : 'variable does not exist' !!}
```

Comment: I had an undefined index in an array and this was the perfect solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in few different ways.

Sample-1:

```
@if( !empty($data['var']))
   {{ $data['var'] }} 
@endif
```

Sample-2:

```
{{ $data['var'] or 'no data found' }}
```

Sample-3: Using ternary operator

```
<a href="" class="{{ ( ! empty($data['var'] ? $data['var'] : 'no data found') }}">
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `@isset` blade directive to check whether the variable is set or not. Alternatively, if you have the default value for that variable you can directly use it as `{{ $vatiable ?? 'default_value' }}`. The `??` way is available in Laravel v5.7 onwards.

If you want to check for multiple variables at once, you can do it by applying AND operation to expression as `@if(isset($var_one) && isset($var_two))`.

There are also other ways (**lengthy**) using `@if` directive as `@if(isset($variable))` but it's not recommended.

Some developer uses `@` symbol for error control in a similar situation. The at-sign (@) is used as error control operator in PHP. When an expression is prepended with the @ sign, error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored. If the `track_errors` feature is enabled, an error message generated by the expression and it will be saved in the variable `$php_errormsg`. This variable will be overwritten on each error. **The use of @ is very bad programming practice** as it does not make the error disappear, it just hides them, and it makes debugging a lot worse since we can’t see what’s actually wrong with our code.

Answer (score 5):

For the last version of Larvael make the variable optional in the blade template. 
Replace `$myvar` with 
`{{ $myvar }} with {{ $myvar?? '' }}`

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to pass to your custom directive? If it's just a string/int  the following should work.

```
Blade::directive('p', function($expression){
    $output = $expression ? $expression : 'nodata';
    return "<?php echo {$output}; ?>";
});
```

In Blade Template

```
@p('Foo')
```

Comment: I want to use it like that `@p($subtitle)` in my view. And If I use your solution I got this error: `Undefined variable: subtitle`

Comment: @pupadupa Have you passed the $subtitle variable to your view? Sounds like blade can't find your variable.

Comment: this is the problem - check in directives if variable doesn't exist. Is there a way to return 'nodata' from directive, if I didnt pass variable to view?

Comment: No, I would assume the error you are receiving is from blade before it even executes the custom directive.

Comment: jeemusu@ it appears in view `Undefined variable: subtitle (View: lp/resources/views/blocks/cover.blade.php) (View: lp/resources/views/blocks/cover.blade.php)`

Comment: @pupadupa the problem is that that variable `$subtitle` doesn't exist. You NEED to pass this to your view from your controller.

Comment: jeemusu@ hm... but why I could use not-existed variable in this way `{{ $checkvariable or 'not-exist' }}` but not in directive? I thought that there should be a way to create logics that check if variable not exist (inside directive)

Comment: Because blade checks to see if the `or` keyword exists, if it does then it doesn't throw an exception because you are passing it a default value.

Answer (score 3):

The `@empty` directive might be useful:

```
@empty($var)
   $var is unset or false-y
@endempty
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if variable exist in Laravel blade directive, do this:

```
Blade::directive('datetime', function ($value) {
    
    return "<?php echo isset($value) ? ($value)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s') : null; ?>";
    
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the value of "$value" automatically without having to pass it from the render. For example just use @something and in the creation of the directive rescue $something

Answer (score 0):

If you trying check a bool  variable you can use @unless

`<input type="text" class="@unless ($variable) d-none @endunless" >`

Comment: The question is about _existence_ of the variable, not the boolean value. _@unless_ will fail if the variable is not set.